# Why do multiple people get muted? (MW3)

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Sometimes when I mute someone two or even three people get muted. Why is this? Are they in a party? [image: only tried muting one player]

Comment: Maybe they're playing from the same console with separate accounts?

Comment: Add in what system you are using

Answer (score 1):

Well from the information that screenshot gives us we know that they are the only two players ingame with mics connected and both of them are muted.

We know that they are the only players with microphones connected purely because every cod game's voip works the same, it displays a little speaker symbol if the mic is plugged in, if it has bars next to it they are talking (the bars represent sound) and if it is crossed with a red x they are muted. If instead of a small speaker we see a small, low detail drawing of people if they are in party chat.

Here are a few possible causes we can draw from that:

- You have previously muted them
- Your playstation network settings deny you from using voice chat with players not in your friendslist
- Your settings automatically mute voicechat if you don't have a headset in

All of these are things you will need to check yourself in both the settings of the game, and of your playstation 3 console.

Also there is the possibility of it being a random glitch, evidence of other players encountering this is found here: https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/995751-call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3/61848344

> It is not a ban, a glitch. Has happened to me before, and some random person i was playing with. If you want to talk with someone party chat works, it will probably work the next day

So it is possible that this is just a temporary issue.

Comment: I meant to add a caption to the image. I muted the player on the top and the bottom player became muted as well. As far as I can remember I’ve never played with them before.

Comment: Make sure you did not press mute all, to what I remember that is an option in MW3, you simply want to just mute the individual.

Comment: mute all isn’t an option for me. I’m on PS3 if that makes a difference.

Comment: It shouldn’t make a difference, maybe I’m remembering MW3 wrong, it’s most likely that they are both on the same console and logged in to different controllers. That may sound weird but usually when two people play on one console muting one will mute both also there is still the chance that this is nothing but a glitch that will go away over time.

Comment: Being the fact I don't have anything to back me up except my experiences; Couple things, @blazeoffury49er mentioned the most common one where you previously muted them prior to your current game.  Another one is if they are playing split screen on two separate accounts, you will mute both if you try to mute one.